# How to paste a cell range automatically - Values only?

Tags: google-sheets

I need some "live" cell data (values only), which get their data from another sheet; an arrayformula is not sufficient.

I'm thinking something that copies column `A:13`-down from Sheet1 (whenever it changes), and then pastes the values, beginning at row 3 of column A on Sheet2.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090447/paste-special-values-google-apps-script) looks like a starting point for me but lacks any mention of doing it automatically when the contents change.

Can anyone help me out?

---

EDIT: Thanks @Tom, my implementation of the script looks like this:

```
/**
 * A function named onEdit will be called whenever
 * a change is made to the spreadsheet.
 * 
 * @param  {object} e The edit event (not used in this case)
 */
function onEdit(e){
  var copyFromRange = 'ReportCalculations!A1:E39';
  var copyToRangeStart = 'Report!A1';
  copyValuesOnly((copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart));
}

/**
 * This function will copy the values from a given range to
 * a second range, which starts from the given cell reference
 * 
 * @param  {string} copyFromRange    Range reference eg: 
 * @param  {string} copyToRangeStart Cell reference eg:
 */
function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

At this point when the `ReportCalculations` sheet is edited, I'm still left with an empty Report sheet – must be missing something

My steps so far:

- Created the new script and saved it
- Tried editing the sheet (nothing)
- Then tried manually running the script from the script manager, which asked me for authorization (which I gave), then tried editing the `ReportCalculations` sheet again and still nothing in the Report sheet.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a doc with us and show us the expected outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an onEdit trigger for the script. That will update whenever changes are made. For example:

```
/**
 * A function named onEdit will be called whenever
 * a change is made to the spreadsheet.
 * 
 * @param  {object} e The edit event (not used in this case)
 */
function onEdit(e){
  var copyFromRange = 'Sheet1!A13:A'; // no row for second cell reference
  var copyToRangeStart = 'Sheet2!A3';
  copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}

/**
 * This function will copy the values from a given range to
 * a second range, which starts from the given cell reference
 * 
 * @param  {string} copyFromRange    Range reference eg: 
 * @param  {string} copyToRangeStart Cell reference eg:
 */
function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers for more details on triggering scripts automatically.

I can't comment yet, so will ask here: Do you need to copy to a second spreadsheet or just a second sheet within the same spreadsheet? The second case is answered above, but I can adjust if you need to copy to a separate spreadsheet?

edit: added code to fully answer the question. Thanks for the guidance Jacob.

Comment: I think it was just an error with quotes ... thanks @Tom trying the script now

Comment: Hi, ok I created the new script, edited the source sheet, but nothing has happened. It did ask for authorization for the onEdit function when I tried to manually run the script using the script manager. What am I missing? Thanks :)

Comment: @Drewdavid: Could you please add a link to the spreadsheet so we can have a look?

Comment: My apologies @Drewdavid - the line `copyValuesOnly((copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart));` should have read `copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);` The extra parentheses were causing the fault. I have changed it in the answer and your Example sheet and it works now. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, just wanted to say this is excellent. Thank You very much for your help, and for tracking with me on it to completion :)