# Copying file with cell data only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been trying to copy file with cell data only but unsuccessfully. I have a Google sheet documnet with importxm function of about 2000 rows. When the function runs it populates the cells but sometimes the connection gets reset and I loose the data. The second function copyValuesOnly works fine for the same sheet. I am passing the range directly but it reuses the sheet every time. So if I automate it it will be writing the current data in the same sheet and it will overwrite it.
I also have a function that I made to save file but I get the exact copy of the file (formulas not data only). Therefore, I am trying to combine both functions but it doesn't really work. How could I save the sheet values in new file instead of in another sheet.
This the post I got one of the functions from:

```
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49952/how-to-paste-a-cell-range-automatically-values-only/116120#116120
```

This is what I am trying to copy the file:

```
function SaveFileData() {
  //file has to be at least readable by the person running the script
var currentdate = new Date(); 
  var datetime = "HW: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
  var fileId = 'fileID'; 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID');
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('fileId');
  copyValuesOnly(file);
  file.makeCopy(datetime, destFolder); 
}


function copyValuesOnly(file) {
  var source = file.getRange('Sheet2!D1:K2000');
  source.copyTo(file.getRange('Sheet1!A1:K2000'), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined. (line 26, file
>   "Logger")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `file.getRange` throws that error, that means `file` is undefined. Look at why that happens. Possibly fileId is wrong.

In any case, getRange is a method of  Spreadsheet, not of File. You need `SpreadsheetApp.openById` to get a Spreadsheet object instead of `DriveApp.getFileById` which returns a File object.